# How to disable connectionpool in tornado logs?

Tags: logging, tornado

I use Tornado to build web app and I redirect the print statements to `tornando.app_log.info`.

However, in my web app I make frequent calls to an external API and every time I do that I get something like this in the logs

```
[I 160722 09:36:00 connectionpool:214] Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
```

How can I remove these messages?

Answer (score 0):

In your `connectionpool.py` you call something like:

```
log.app_log.info('Starting new HTTP connection', ...)
```

If you don't want to see that message, remove that line. Alternatively, call "debug" instead of "info", then you'll only see that error if you turn logging up to the "debug" level like:

```
./my_script.py --logging=debug
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is that I don't have this `log.app_log.info('Starting new HTTP connection', ...)` anywhere in my code. This message pops up every time I do a `request` to a third part service (and no matter of the service I use I always get the same message).